# Diversas tabelas que deveriam representar uma única entidade

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Estou atualizando um sistema que possui onze tabelas que representam uma única entidade, acredito que por erro de implementação, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
Entidade: Foo

Tabela Foo1 - Campo1, Campo2, Campo3
Tabela Foo2 - Campo1, Campo2, Campo3
Tabela Foo3 - Campo1, Campo2, Campo3, Campo4
[...]
```

Por causa desta implementação, existem onze entidades no sistema que herdam de Foo, com seus respectivos repositórios e serviços. Esta implementação causou impacto direto no código, que possui `n switchs` que definem qual entidade deva ser utilizada. Os `cases` possuem o mesmo código, com exceção dos repositórios e serviços utilizados.

O refactor do banco de dados e das entidades atualmente não é uma opção.

Diante deste cenário, qual seria a melhor abordagem para lidar com esta situação? O código realizado até o momento não deverá ser alterado, mas existe um esforço muito grande para criar novas funcionalidades que dependam dessa arquitetura de N tabelas e N entidades que deveriam representar apenas uma. Existe algum design pattern que possa facilitar este trabalho?

A arquitetura do projeto está em Onion com camada de apresentação MVC.
A camada MVC acessa os services que por sua vez encapsulam a regra de negócio do sistema. Um problema comum dessa implementação é que sempre que algo envolve essas entidades e tabelas, um switch precisa ser feito para definir-se qual serviço será chamado para comunicar-se com o banco de dados.

```
public class FooService{
    private service1;
    private service2;
    //demais services das entidades

    //construtor

    public void Inserir(Entidade foo)
    {
        switch(bar.TipoItem)
        {
            case(TipoItemEnum.Tabela1):
                service1.RealizarAlgumProcesso(foo);
                break;
            case(TipoItemEnum.Tabela2):
                service2.RealizarAlgumProcesso(foo);
                break;
            //demais cases para os demais services.
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual versão do .Net está o projeto?

Comment: A primeira vista, me parece um caso para uma Factory, poderia nos dar mais informações?

Comment: está utilizando MVC 4. @Intruso, poderia especificar quais informações você gostaria de saber?

Comment: Todos os Services também também implementam uma mesma interface?

Comment: Cada service implementa uma interface diferente, @TobyMosque

Comment: Te aconselho a deixar este fato bem explicito na sua questão, e dê nomes diferentes ao método de cada service, acredito que outros tiveram este mesmo intendimento, pois as respostas estão seguindo esta linha de raciocinio.

Comment: O services implementam uma interface comum?

Comment: Conforme dito a @TobyMosque, os services implementam interfaces diferentes.

Comment: Estes serviços estão em uma biblioteca local ou são web Services (eg: WCF)? Existe a possibilidade de todos os serviços implementarem uma interface em.comum? Ou realmente são procedimentos muito distintos para cada entidade?

Comment: @TobyMosque, os procedimentos são semelhantes sim, com poucas mudanças na regra de negócio, contudo, devido ao fato de existir 12 tabelas e 12 entidades, todo o sistema foi projetado como se estas funcionalidades fossem separadas.

Comment: @Vinícius, tudo bem, as interfaces são diferentes, mas, os atributos e metodos possuem diferentes assinaturas? Ou poderia ser encapsulados em um subsistema e deixar o polimorfismo fazer o resto através de uma fachada (facade)?

Comment: Concordo com o @Intruso que isso pode ter cara de **Facade**, apesar de ter um _Bad Smell_ pedindo refatoração... :) Segue um link legal sobre o padrão: http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern

Comment: @Intruso, os atributos variam pouco e os métodos poderiam ser comum. Infelizmente, hoje não está assim, mas para as funcionalidades que virão pode ser feito. A fachada parece ser uma boa ideia, embora essa abordagem fuja da arquitetura Onion. Criar uma fachada não seria semelhante a criar um service em comum para todas estas tabelas?

Comment: @Vinicius, pra escolher pense no longo prazo. Sugeri isso (facade) porque você falou que não é possivel refatorar, mas, o trabalho de concentrar a complexidade de criação de objetos no seu cenário acho que deveria ser feito com uma Factory. Se os metodos e atributos são claramente similares, é muito provavel que seja fácil a refatoração incluindo um interface e fazendo com que os serviços herdem dela, dependendo da similaridade, você fazia apenas uma limpeza nos switchs espalhados e a factory faz o resto. Fazer o service vai ter o mesmo efeito da Fachada, mas, a fachada é um padrão de projeto.

Answer (score 3):

Sim. O nome dela é [**Helper**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helper_class), que é uma variação do [**Utility**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_pattern).

Como os métodos são muito parecidos, você pode centralizar a lógica comum de negócios dentro do *Helper* e chamar apenas um método só que faz tudo.

Coloque por favor exemplos de lógica de negócios na pergunta que eu coloco na resposta como refatorar sua lógica para um *Helper*.

---

### Camada de Serviços

Supondo seu exemplo, posso reimplementar um `Service` usando uma abordagem genérica. Por exemplo:

```
public class ClasseService<T>
    where T: Foo 
{
    public void RealizarAlgumProcesso(T objeto) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Verificações específicas do tipo derivado podem ser feitas da seguinte forma:

```
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Foo1)) { ... }
```

Sei que ainda não é o adequado, mas é um ponto de partida.

Comment: Pergunta editada, cigano.

Answer (score 1):

No .Net 4.0 temos a opção do dynamic, eu não recomendaria o uso levianamente, mas na sua situação pode vir a calhar.

Crie uma factory que receba como parâmetro o tipo de tabela e devolva o serviço correspondente, para evitar refatorar o código e criar uma(s) interfaces e programar polimorficamente você pode usar o dynamic e invocar em runtime o método. O contraponto é performance e perda do intellisense.

Isso só vai funcionar se todos os serviços tem o mesmo nome de métodos.

Ex:

```
    public static class MyFactory
    {
        public static dynamic GetService(TableType type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case TableType.Table1:
                    return new Service1();
                case TableType.Table2:
                    return new Service2();
                case TableType.Table3:
                    return new Service3();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public enum TableType 
    {
        Table1,
        Table2,
        Table3,
    }


public class Service1 { public int Xpto(int i) { return i; } }
public class Service2 { public double Xpto(double d) { return d; } }
public class Service3 { public string Xpto(string s) { return s; } }
```

Uso com retorno e parametros distintos:

```
var service = MyFactory.GetService(TableType.Table1);
Console.WriteLine(service.Xpto(1));

service = MyFactory.GetService(TableType.Table2);
Console.WriteLine(service.Xpto(4.0));

service = MyFactory.GetService(TableType.Table3);
Console.WriteLine(service.Xpto("Xpto"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A arquitetura dos serviços deve seguir a mesma arquitetura das entidades e para isso você deve utilizar o polimorfismo dos seus objetos de serviço e encapsular somente aquilo que cada um precisa. No exemplo dado, uma implementação mais flexível seria criar uma interface genérica que contenha o método a ser utilizado e criar um serviço para cada tipo de entidade que implemente essa interface. Será necessário para isso uma classe seletora, que é aquela que terá somente a lógica do que está no switch. Dessa forma todo código estará com o encapsulamento devido. Segue a refatoração do exemplo que você postou:

```
public class FooService
{
    public void Inserir(object foo)
    {
        IService insertService = InsertServiceSelector.GetService(foo);
        insertService.RealizarAlgumProcesso(foo);
    }
}

interface IService
{
    void RealizarAlgumProcesso(object foo);
}

class StringService : IService
{
    public void RealizarAlgumProcesso(object foo)
    {
        string bar = (string) foo;
        /* ...Serviço para Strings... */
    }
}

class IntegerService : IService
{
    public void RealizarAlgumProcesso(object foo)
    {
        int bar = (int) foo;
        /* ...Serviço para inteiros.. */
    }
}

class InsertServiceSelector
{
    public static IService GetService(object foo)
    {
        if(foo is string)
            return new StringService();

        if (foo is int)
            return new IntegerService();

        /*... A lógica de seleção fica encapsulada...*/

    }
}
```